# iOS app badge persists

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, local

I have an iPhone app which uses local notification. It is working almost perfectly, although I have a little problem: The red balloon (app badge) from notification doesn't dismiss when I launch the app. What can I do to fix it?

I've already deleted the app from iPhone, but when I compile it again with Xcode, I comes back again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
```

after you have processed your notification.